# NET Core - Submit on input change, not button click

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Currently, I have a form that calls a method in my controller. It sends a string as a parameter to my `IActionResult` (the string is always a numer since I am getting it from an input of type range between 1 and 12). The method looks like this: `public IActionResult ChangeForecastMonths(string forecastMonths)` The code in my view is the following:

```
<form asp-action="ChangeForecastMonths">
    <input asp-for="FutureForecastMonths" name="forecastMonths" type="range" class="custom-range" min="1" max="12" step="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is -- instead of the `ChangeForecastMonths` method being called whenever the submit button is clicked -- to actually have it called whenever the input field changes its value.

Comment: Have you [done any research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) or [made any attempts to solve the issue](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)? There is a JavaScript-exposed `onchange` event on the `input` element...

Comment: Could you call the .submit() function on the form from the onchange event of the input?

Comment: @Wizard-of-Koz I expressed no dislike. I merely asked a question, as there was no evidence in the only place I could find it, the written question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey "relative quality of the question to other people coming to the question" -- Is is the problem that I have no stated the question clear, or that I have not included my research and attempts, like your previously said? What is unclear about my problem and how can the description be better?

Comment: @Wizard-of-Koz Again, I did not downvote the question, so asking me why someone else downvoted the question is barking up the wrong tree. I made a comment with what I found lacking in the question, with links to pages with information on what the problems are and how to fix them. It's your choice as to whether you read those and follow the advice. I've said my peace in regards to this question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hook to the `change()` event of the input, then fire a `submit()` on the parent form, like this:

```
<form asp-action="ChangeForecastMonths">
  <input asp-for="FutureForecastMonths" name="forecastMonths" type="range" class="custom-range" min="1" max="12" step="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
  <script>
    $('form input').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
  </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]